# A questions about "wipe" in CWM Recovery

Tags: security, clockworkmod-recovery, delete

CWM Recovery has a many options for wipe and format partitions, and the options are:

- wipe data/factory reset.
- wipe cache partition.
- format boot, system, data, cache, sdcard or sd-ext.
- wipe dalvik cache.
- wipe battery stats.

  1. I wonder What is the difference between a wipe and format In terms of safe deletion of data?
  2. How can I Completely Wipe Data from all partitions of phone device?
     (I want do that before install a new ROM).
  3. What is the overwriting Standard used in the wipe? ,thanx in advance.

Note: I don't know version of CWM Recovery but I'll use CWM Recovery from here:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/honor-4c/development/honor-4c-root-cwm-recovery-inshaalmirza-t3177770

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I wonder What is the difference between a wipe and format In terms of safe deletion of data?

A wipe is, in any method, removes selected data from filesystem. It can be plain deletion or formatting the partition.

A format is a complete reset of a disk partition, by cleaning everything up and re-build its headers, inode records, file allocation tables, etc.

> 2. How can I Completely Wipe Data from all partitions of phone device? (I want do that before install a new ROM).

Use the 1st option **wipe data/factory reset**. That's enough.

> 3. What is the overwriting Standard used in the wipe? ,thanx in advance.

AFAIK there's no overwriting. It simply deletes files and/or formats partitions of your phone.

Comment: Add to 1.: the Format option is intended a.o. to *change the file system*. You can e.g. format a partition previously using vfat to ext4, or from ext4 to f2fs (not checked which systems CWM recovery supports, so don't nail me on that). Wipe usually is format without switching the fs (faster than delete) unless you define otherwise, at least with TWRP. // 2.: to be on the absolute safe side, one would also wipe system – but aggreed, that's optional and usually not needed.